# How to using a double join in a single select statement in t-sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a bit of a puzzle here is my query:

```
select FullName as Leader,FullName as Contact from Employee
inner join ConvTracking
on LeaderId=EmpId
```

this bit will select fullname from the employee table based on the employee id
in the convtracking table I have 2 columns one is `LeaderId` and the other is `ContactId`
is it possible to pull both the leader full name and contact full name in a single query given that the Id is basically the employee id?

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you want an answer you need to provide more details so we can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on what exactly is your question but if I understood correctly you have a table ConvTracking with columns ContactId and LeaderId. Both of those columns are foreign keys of Employee table EmpId column. If yes, the below could help but to be honest I am finding it hard to understand your question.

```
select e2.FullName as Leader, e1.FullName as Contact 
from Employee as e1 
inner join ConvTracking as c on e1.EmpId = c.ContactId
inner join Employee as e2 on c.LeaderId = e2.EmpId
```